# Call all tribal vassals to war

Tags: crusader-kings-2

The wiki says there is a button to call all vassals to war in the military tab but I can't find it in any part of the tab; where is it?

The only DLC I don't have is Horse Lords and my tribal vassals are definitely my allies.

Comment: Alongside the raise levies and raise vassal levies button on the military tab; there is an extra button (to the left) this one will say 'call allies to war' or some similar thing. Certainly it will send a request to all allied forces (whether they accept depends on relationship). I do not know for sure about tribal play, however I assume it is the same button from what you describe

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will work but I found this online apparently 
you can raise tribal authority to medium, the you can raise you tribal vassals as levies instead of having them call to war.

Now I know this Is not a direct answer to your question but it is the best I found.